# ¿Cómo puedo hacer uso de las banderas en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, web, aplicación-web

Estoy haciendo un juego web y tengo cuatro imágenes de frijoles, lo que necesito hacer es que al terminar de pulsar las cuatro imágenes se active una flecha para avanzar al siguiente nivel. Esto es independientemente del orden que le den clic a las cuatro imágenes pero que la flecha se active cuando se termine de elegir las cuatro imágenes, se puede comenzar dando clic de arriba hacia abajo, inverso o comenzado por en medio.
Este es el link del juego web: https://oswaldo5.github.io/quitandoCuatroEnCuatro/

```js
//  HYPE.documents["quitando de 4 en 4 prueba"]

(function(){(function m(){function k(a,b,c,d){var e=!1;null==window[a]&&(null==window[b]?(window[b]=[],window[b].push(m),a=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],b=document.createElement("script"),e=l,false==!0&&(e=""),b.type="text/javascript",""!=d&&(b.integrity=d,b.setAttribute("crossorigin","anonymous")),b.src=e+"/"+c,a.appendChild(b)):window[b].push(m),e=!0);return e}var l="quitando%20de%204%20en%204%20prueba.hyperesources",f="quitando de 4 en 4 prueba",g="quitandode4en4prueba_hype_container";if(false==
!1)try{for(var c=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),a=0;a<c.length;a++){var d=c[a].src,b=null!=d?d.indexOf("/quitandode4en4prueba_hype_generated_script.js"):-1;if(-1!=b){l=d.substr(0,b);break}}}catch(p){}c=navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+)/);c=parseFloat(c&&c[1])||null;d=!0==(null!=window.HYPE_674F||null!=window.HYPE_dtl_674F)||false==!0||null!=c&&10>c;a=!0==d?"HYPE-674.full.min.js":"HYPE-674.thin.min.js";c=!0==d?"F":"T";d=d?"":
"";if(false==!1&&(a=k("HYPE_674"+c,"HYPE_dtl_674"+c,a,d),false==!0&&(a=a||k("HYPE_w_674","HYPE_wdtl_674","HYPE-674.waypoints.min.js","")),false==!0&&(a=a||k("Matter","HYPE_pdtl_674","HYPE-674.physics.min.js","")),a))return;d=window.HYPE.documents;if(null!=d[f]){b=1;a=f;do f=""+a+"-"+b++;while(null!=d[f]);for(var e=document.getElementsByTagName("div"),
b=!1,a=0;a<e.length;a++)if(e[a].id==g&&null==e[a].getAttribute("HYP_dn")){var b=1,h=g;do g=""+h+"-"+b++;while(null!=document.getElementById(g));e[a].id=g;b=!0;break}if(!1==b)return}b=[];b=[];e={};h={};for(a=0;a<b.length;a++)try{h[b[a].identifier]=b[a].name,e[b[a].name]=eval("(function(){return "+b[a].source+"})();")}catch(n){window.console&&window.console.log(n),e[b[a].name]=function(){}}c=new window["HYPE_674"+c](f,g,{"7":{p:1,n:"Pasted_2x.png",g:"74",o:true,t:"@2x"},"3":{p:1,n:"vaso%20vacio_2x.jpg",g:"16",o:true,t:"@2x"},"-2":{n:"blank.gif"},"4":{p:1,n:"frijol.png",g:"18",o:true,t:"@1x"},"0":{p:1,n:"Captura%20de%20Pantalla%202020-06-25%20a%20la%28s%29%209.20.32-1.jpg",g:"9",o:true,t:"@1x"},"5":{p:1,n:"frijol_2x.png",g:"18",o:true,t:"@2x"},"1":{p:1,n:"Captura%20de%20Pantalla%202020-06-25%20a%20la%28s%29%209.20.32-1_2x.jpg",g:"9",o:true,t:"@2x"},"6":{p:1,n:"Pasted.png",g:"74",o:true,t:"@1x"},"2":{p:1,n:"vaso%20vacio.jpg",g:"16",o:true,t:"@1x"},"-1":{n:"PIE.htc"}},l,[],e,[{n:"Escena sin t\u00edtulo",o:"1",X:[0]},{n:"Escena sin t\u00edtulo 2",o:"12",X:[1]}],
[{o:"3",p:"600px",cA:false,Y:600,Z:400,L:[],c:"#FFF",bY:1,d:600,U:{},T:{kTimelineDefaultIdentifier:{q:false,z:0,i:"kTimelineDefaultIdentifier",n:"Main Timeline",a:[],f:30,b:[]}},bZ:180,O:["77","76"],n:"Dise\u00f1o sin t\u00edtulo","_":0,v:{"77":{aU:8,G:"#000",c:450,aV:8,r:"inline",d:28,s:"Futura,Verdana,sans-serif",t:29,Z:"break-word",aP:"pointer",w:"Quitando frijoles: de 4 en 4",j:"absolute",x:"visible",k:"div",y:"preserve",dB:"button",z:2,aS:8,aT:8,a:94,b:24},"76":{h:"9",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:195,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",aA:{a:[{d:1.1,p:1,g:1,f:1}]},z:1,b:91,d:269,k:"div",c:210,aP:"pointer"}}},{o:"14",p:"600px",cA:false,Y:600,Z:400,L:[],c:"#FFF",bY:1,d:600,U:{},T:{"63":{q:false,z:0.15,i:"63",n:"f1",a:[{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"a",e:620,s:391,o:"113"},{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"b",e:50,s:110,o:"113"},{y:0.15,i:"a",s:620,z:0,o:"113",f:"c"},{y:0.15,i:"b",s:50,z:0,o:"113",f:"c"}],f:30,b:[]},"66":{q:false,z:0.15,i:"66",n:"f4",a:[{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"a",e:600,s:391,o:"114"},{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"b",e:364,s:233,o:"114"},{y:0.15,i:"a",s:600,z:0,o:"114",f:"c"},{y:0.15,i:"b",s:364,z:0,o:"114",f:"c"}],f:30,b:[]},kTimelineDefaultIdentifier:{q:false,z:0,i:"kTimelineDefaultIdentifier",n:"Main Timeline",a:[],f:30,b:[]},"65":{q:false,z:0.15,i:"65",n:"f3",a:[{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"a",e:305,s:391,o:"115"},{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"b",e:405,s:192,o:"115"},{y:0.15,i:"a",s:305,z:0,o:"115",f:"c"},{y:0.15,i:"b",s:405,z:0,o:"115",f:"c"}],f:30,b:[]},"64":{q:false,z:0.15,i:"64",n:"f2",a:[{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"a",e:-57,s:391,o:"112"},{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"b",e:322,s:151,o:"112"},{y:0.15,i:"a",s:-57,z:0,o:"112",f:"c"},{y:0.15,i:"b",s:322,z:0,o:"112",f:"c"}],f:30,b:[]},"73":{q:false,z:0.15,i:"73",n:"fle",a:[{f:"c",y:0,z:0.15,i:"e",e:1,s:0,o:"116"},{y:0.15,i:"e",s:1,z:0,o:"116",f:"c"}],f:30,b:[]}},bZ:180,O:["116","78","113","91","90","80","79","102","101","112","99","88","110","98","87","100","89","109","111","115","97","86","108","96","92","85","81","95","84","107","103","106","93","82","104","94","83","105","114"],n:"Dise\u00f1o sin t\u00edtulo","_":1,v:{"86":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:43,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:7,bF:"79",b:60,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"95":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:68,a:43,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"90",z:5,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"78":{aV:8,w:"Quita 4 frijoles<br>",x:"visible",a:159,Z:"break-word",y:"preserve",j:"absolute",r:"inline",b:40,yy:"nowrap",s:"Futura,Verdana,sans-serif",z:1,aS:8,t:37,aT:8,k:"div",aU:8,G:"#000"},"87":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:15,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:8,bF:"79",b:48,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"116":{h:"74",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:470,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:16,b:29,k:"div",d:114,c:109,e:0,aP:"pointer"},"96":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:16,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:6,bF:"90",b:62,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"103":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:16,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:2,bF:"101",b:68,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"79":{k:"div",x:"visible",c:115,d:123,z:4,a:127,j:"absolute",b:143},"88":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:32,a:44,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"79",z:9,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"97":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:43,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:7,bF:"90",b:60,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"89":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:44,a:44,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"79",z:10,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"104":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:41,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:3,bF:"101",b:80,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"98":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:15,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:8,bF:"90",b:48,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"110":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:32,a:44,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"101",z:9,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"99":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:32,a:44,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"90",z:9,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"105":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:25,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:4,bF:"101",b:84,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"111":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:44,a:44,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"101",z:10,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"106":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:68,a:43,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"101",z:5,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"112":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:391,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",aA:{a:[{b:"64",p:3,z:false,symbolOid:"13"}]},z:13,b:151,d:36,k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer"},"80":{h:"16",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:0,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:1,bF:"79",b:0,d:123,k:"div",c:115},"107":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:16,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:6,bF:"101",b:62,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"81":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:16,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:2,bF:"79",b:68,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"90":{k:"div",x:"visible",c:115,d:123,z:11,a:127,j:"absolute",b:143},"113":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:391,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",aA:{a:[{b:"63",p:3,z:false,symbolOid:"13"}]},z:14,b:110,d:36,k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer"},"82":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:41,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:3,bF:"79",b:80,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"100":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:44,a:44,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"90",z:10,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"108":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:43,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:7,bF:"101",b:60,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"91":{h:"16",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:0,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:1,bF:"90",b:0,d:123,k:"div",c:115},"83":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:25,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:4,bF:"79",b:84,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"92":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:16,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:2,bF:"90",b:68,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"114":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:391,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",aA:{a:[{b:"66",p:3,z:false,symbolOid:"13"},{b:"73",p:3,z:false,symbolOid:"13"}]},z:15,b:233,d:36,k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer"},"101":{k:"div",x:"visible",c:115,d:123,z:12,a:247,j:"absolute",b:143},"109":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:15,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:8,bF:"101",b:48,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"93":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:41,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:3,bF:"90",b:80,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"84":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",tY:0.5,q:"100% 100%",b:68,a:43,r:"inline",j:"absolute",bF:"79",z:5,d:36,dB:"img",k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer",tX:0.5},"85":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:16,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:6,bF:"79",b:62,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"115":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:391,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",aA:{a:[{b:"65",p:3,z:false,symbolOid:"13"}]},z:17,b:192,d:36,k:"div",c:57,aP:"pointer"},"94":{h:"18",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:25,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:4,bF:"90",b:84,d:36,k:"div",c:57},"102":{h:"16",p:"no-repeat",x:"visible",a:0,dB:"img",q:"100% 100%",j:"absolute",r:"inline",z:1,bF:"101",b:0,d:123,k:"div",c:115}}}],{},h,{},null,false,true,-1,true,true,false,true,true);d[f]=c.API;document.getElementById(g).setAttribute("HYP_dn",f);c.z_o(this.body)})();})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
    <title>quitando de 4 en 4 prueba</title>
    <style>
        html {
            height:100%;
        }
        body {
            background-color:#FFF;
            margin:0;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- copy these lines to your document head: -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=600" />

    <!-- end copy -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- copy these lines to your document: -->

    <div id="quitandode4en4prueba_hype_container" class="HYPE_document" style="margin:auto;position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;overflow:hidden;">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="quitando%20de%204%20en%204%20prueba.hyperesources/quitandode4en4prueba_hype_generated_script.js?89479"></script>
    </div>

    <!-- end copy -->
    


    <!-- text content for search engines: -->

    <div style="display:none" aria-hidden=true>

        <div>Quitando frijoles: de 4 en 4</div>
        <div>Quita 4 frijoles
</div>

    </div>

    <!-- end text content: -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actualmente aparece una fecla al sacar los frijoles, cual es el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No he revisado tú código, pero al jugar solo veo un error de lógica.

Veo 4 frijoles, y al dar click recién al último frijol se activa al flecha que te lleva la siguiente nivel.

[image: jugando]

Entonces, lo que tu tienes que hacer es crear un contador que acumule las veces que llevas quitando los frijoles.

Sí yo tengo lo siguiente **var iContadorFrijoles = 0;** voy aumentando el contador conforme quito los frijoles, entonces en cada evento donde quitas un frijol realizas **iContadorFrijoles++;**

Y solo activas la flecha sí **if( iContadorFrijoles == 4 && OtherConditions ) {...}** para tu siguiente nivel, debes devolver el valor de **iContadorFrijoles  = 0**.

**OtherConditions** en la sentencia **if** son las otras condiciones que puedas tener para tu problema, sí las hubiera.

Creo que eso es todo, si compartes tu código tal vez sea más fácil indicarte en que líneas.

Comment: Si tu estuvieras programando solo esa parte, ¿Cómo quedaría tu código?

Comment: 1. Crear contador de pasas   
2. Colocar y seguido aumentar el contador de pasas en al función que retira una pasa.   
3. añadir una condición en la función que verifica si activar el siguiente nivel.   
Sí tienes el código tal vez pueda orientarte mejor.

Comment: Ya pude agregar el código, de hecho está un poco complejo porque lo generé por medio de interfaz gráfica, pero me gustaría solucionar ese problema.